# Exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'

Tags: odoo, rml

Please i am using rml to create a new report in OpenERP.
So that i use in my rml this code to create for each result a new td but the problem is that i got Exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag' as an error.
Here is my code:

```
    <tr>
    <para style="P7">[[ repeatIn(get_employee_lines(), 'o', 'td') ]]</para> 
  <td> 
    <para style="P9">NOM EMPLOYÉ</para>
  </td>

    <td>
      <para style="P7">[[ o['name'] ]]</para>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So, please who can help me to find the solution really need help.
Here is all the error:

```
 2015-09-01 10:21:45,562 6030 ERROR openerp openerp.service.web_services:    Exception: 'NoneType' object has no  attribute 'tag'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 712, in go
(result, format) = obj.create(cr, uid, ids, datas, context)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/report/report_sxw.py", line 443, in create
    fnct_ret = fnct(cr, uid, ids, data, report_xml, context)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/report/report_sxw.py", line 512, in create_source_pdf
    return self.create_single_pdf(cr, uid, ids, data, report_xml, context)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/report/report_sxw.py", line 530, in create_single_pdf
    processed_rml = self.preprocess_rml(processed_rml,report_xml.report_type)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/report/preprocess.py", line 82, in preprocess_rml
self.preprocess_rml(node,type)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/report/preprocess.py", line 82, in preprocess_rml
    self.preprocess_rml(node,type)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/report/preprocess.py", line 82, in preprocess_rml
self.preprocess_rml(node,type)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/report/preprocess.py", line 77, in preprocess_rml
t = _regex1.sub(_sub1, node.text or node.tail)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/report/preprocess.py", line 73, in _sub1
while n.tag not in match:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'
2015-09-01 10:21:45,793 6030 ERROR openerp openerp.netsvc: 'NoneType' object     has no attribute 'tag'
(<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'",), <traceback object at 0x7fdea5a5c950>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 654, in dispatch
res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 760, in exp_report_get
return self._check_report(report_id)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 738, in _check_report
netsvc.abort_response(exc, exc.message, 'warning', exc.traceback)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 71, in abort_response
raise openerp.osv.osv.except_osv(description, details)
except_osv: (u"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'", (<type     'exceptions.AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no     attribute 'tag'",), <traceback object at 0x7fdea5a5c950>))
```

Comment: This question was answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

Comment: its the same error but not the same thing. It is due to td in the repeatin so i want to know how to use it in rml

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not an error dump. Please only ask explicit questions here. Just posting your code hoping for others to debug it is also not appreciated.

Comment: please why dont you, instead of upvoting my question and saying notes, trying to help me find the solution. I think i am not doing anything wrong no??!!! try to think with me it will be better than destroying my abilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.

First, i had to change the version of my OpenOffice which is v4.1.X.

Second, i used [[ repeatIn(get_employee_lines(example.company_id,example.date_start,example.date_end), 'o', 'td') ]] which Loop on every line and make a new table cell for each line.
So here is the right answer:

```
    <tr>
      <td>
         <para style="P8">NOM EMPLOYÉ</para>
      </td>
      <td>
      <para style="P7">[[ repeatIn(get_employee_lines(example.company_id,example.date_start,example.d              ate_end), 'o', 'td') ]]</para>
       <para style="P7">[[ o['name'] ]]</para>
      </td>
      </tr>
```

Best Regards.